# Open api specification for Azure Iothub devices

Tags: azure, go, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge, azure-iot-hub-device-management

I can't seem to find open api spec for azure iothub devices related operations. I'm talking about specifically these [operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/service/devices). I need openapi spec so that I can use [autorest](https://github.com/Azure/autorest) to genrate client code in golang.